# Auto-rise and hover return header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am wanting a header that stays on the top of the browser regardless of where you scroll (fixed), that will auto rise up, off the page until some interaction is given again. One other thing, if you scroll back up to the top of the page (or is still there) the header won't disapear, only when the spot where it would be, is above your screen. I hope I've been clear. If anyone could direct me to a JS-Fiddle or anywhere else. Or just answer it, that would be great!

Here's my code so-far. And https://jsfiddle.net/olivermurfett/xsodwnno/ if you want to visualize it.

HTML:

```
<div class = "header" id = "header">

    <img style="width: 100%; position: absolute;  height: 46px; " src="Gradient-Background_121.jpg">
    <p class = "header-heading">OliverMurfett<small><small>.com</small></small></p>
    <p class = "header-links" style = "text-align: right;"> 
        <a href="" class = "hvr-underline-from-center" data-hover="Home" >Home</a>
        <a href="" class = "hvr-underline-from-center" data-hover="About" >About</a>
        <a href="" class = "hvr-underline-from-center" data-hover="Contact Me" >Contact Me</a>
    </p>
    <div style = "clear: both"> </div>
</div>



<div class = "content-body" id="content-body">
    <p>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.header {
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;

}

.header-heading {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
}

.header-links {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
}

.header-links a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgba(94, 94, 94, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(94, 94, 94, 0);
    -webkit-transition: border 500ms;
    -moz-transition: border 500ms;
    -ms-transition: border 500ms;
    -o-transition: border 500ms;
    transition: border 500ms; 

}

.header-links  a::before {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    color: black;;
    position: absolute;

    transition: transform 500ms, opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms, opacity 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms, opacity 500ms;
}



.header-links a:hover::before,
.header-links a:focus::before {
    opacity: 0;
}

.header-links a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(94, 94, 94, 1);

}

.content-body {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    height: blue;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 595px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 46px;
}
```

Comment: You want like http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/ ?

Comment: @ketan yes thanks but also so that if you hover over that header it appears